# Website Feature Toggling in Production

Tags: web, toggle

I'm setting up a dogfooding website that allows me to enable features only for that site.

The dogfooding site will be a user on a production level website.  The dogfooding site will then use all features within the dogfood toggle, whereas the other production users will not have that experience.

Is there is an efficient way to manage these feature toggles effectively to prevent manually trying to add and remove things like "if" statements on all these features?

Eventually we will need to be able to toggle html, javascript, and c#.  We are not worried about schema changes since those aren't within the scope of dogfooding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the best way to handle this is to just self-monitor each of the tags and set up configurations to prevent "if" type statements from polluting production.

There doesn't seem to be a clean pre-built solution at this point.